# TRANSPOSING: How to copy a cell value into the 'Sheet' part of formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reference the data from another sheet, but I'd like to be able to dynamically specify the Sheet name via a cell within this sheet.

Let's say cell A1 has the text "Sheet 1"

Instead of having my formula say:

=TRANSPOSE('Sheet 1'!F2:F121)

I need to find a way to insert the data from cell A1:

=TRANSPOSE('***reference text from A1***'!F2:F121)

Is there a way of doing this? I'm working in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(A1&"!F2:F121"))`